# The mysql problems(select * from my table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get a column from my table, but something wrong. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xInfA.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYmU9.jpg)

This problem is strange, I select * from order(a table of my database), but I cannot do that, I don't know where is wrong.

Comment: If you are not going to bother writing a question, no one is going to bother writing an answer.

Comment: Please explain your problem in text, not in images.

Comment: @jbafford Thanks. I explain my problem in my text.

Answer (score 2):

order is a reserved keyword in MySql where it is generally used to order output with reference to particular coloumn.

General logic of any coding or database structure is to avoid reserved keywords by that particular coding language or databases.

check the following link for reserved keywords in mysql

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

In your case to resolve the issue , simply use back tick (" ` ") for the word order i.e.

```
select * from `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL. You will need to escape such a table name in your SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `order`;
```

But it would be better would be to not use that as a table name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the table order or use `` before and after it so the code will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `order`;
```